# Using panda for comparing column values and creating column based on the values in compared columns?

Tags: python, pandas

I am very new to python and pandas. I have following example CSV as input.

```
ID Name Activity 
1   AB    Play
2   AD    Hurt
3   cd    Polite
4   CA    Play
```

I want to transform this to

```
ID Name Activity NumActivity
1   AB    Play     1
2   AD    Hurt     2
3   cd    Polite   3
4   CA    Play     1
```

So basically, I want to give numeric value to the strings in the column for activity.

Since I am very new to pandas, I am approaching this forum for help.

thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`factorize`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.factorize.html):

```
In [6]:
df['NumActivity'] = pd.factorize(df['Activity'])[0] +1
df

Out[6]:
   ID Name Activity  NumActivity
0   1   AB     Play            1
1   2   AD     Hurt            2
2   3   cd   Polite            3
3   4   CA     Play            1
```

Here `factorize` returns a tuple containing array pairs:

```
In [8]:
pd.factorize(df['Activity'])

Out[8]:
(array([0, 1, 2, 0]), Index(['Play', 'Hurt', 'Polite'], dtype='object'))
```

So we index the first element using `[0]` and seeing as you want your index to start from `1` we `+1` to the values.

Comment: Thanks a lot. df['NumActivity'] = pd.factorize(df['Activity'])[0] +1 works. But when I try to add new column using df['NumActivity'] = pd.factorize(df['Activity'])[0] +1 I get KeyError: 'numActivity'. It seems that it is not creating this new column. how do I get this resolved?

Comment: Thanks a lot. df['NumActivity'] = pd.factorize(df['Activity'])[0] +1 works. But when I try to add new column using df['NumActivity'] = pd.factorize(df['Activity'])[0] +1 I get KeyError: 'numActivity'. It seems that it is not creating this new column. how do I get this resolved?

Comment: your code and error don't make sense you mention `NumActivity` but your key error states `numActivity` which is it? Also post updates to your question not as comments